# Android: Button onClicklistener not working after switching fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, dagger-hilt

I have a very weird problem. When I navigate from `Fragment 1` to `Fragment 2` using a `btn.setOnClickListener` and then navigating back from `Fragment 2` to `Fragment 1` using the back button, the `btn.setOnClickListener` in `Fragment 1` does not work anymore and therefore is not able to navigate to `Fragment 2` again.

Here is my code:

### Button XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

// Custom Background for the button
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/materialToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/btnColorGray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Main XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.view.fragments.home.calibrateAndRepair.CalibrateRepairMessageFragment">

    ... some other stuff

    <!-- Included the button -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/calibrate_repair_btn"
        layout="@layout/calibrate_repair_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### BaseFragment for databinding

```
abstract class BaseFragment<out T: ViewDataBinding>(val layout: Int) : Fragment() {
    abstract val viewModel: ViewModel
    private val _navController by lazy { findNavController() }
    val navController: NavController
        get() = _navController

    
    fun navigateTo(fragment: Int, bundle: Bundle? = null) {
        _navController.navigate(fragment, bundle)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return DataBindingUtil.inflate<T>(inflater, layout, container, false).apply {
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
            setVariable(BR.viewModel, viewModel)
            Timber.d("Created BaseFragment and binded View")
        }.root
    }
}
```

### EmailFragment for initializing the button

```
abstract class EmailFragment<out T: ViewDataBinding>(
    layout: Int,
    private val progressBarDescription: ArrayList<String>,
    private val stateNumber: StateProgressBar.StateNumber
) : BaseFragment<T>(layout) {

    abstract val next: Int
    abstract val bundleNext: Bundle?
    // getting the button from the button.xml
    private val btnNext: MaterialButton by lazy { btn_next_calibrate }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // ... some other initializing which constantly work!
        initButton()
    }

    // Initializing the button
    private fun initButton() {
        btnNext.setOnClickListener {
            navigateTo(next, bundleNext)
            Timber.d("Button clicked")
        }
    }
}
```

### Fragment 1

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class CalibrateRepairMessageFragment(
    private val progressBarDescription: ArrayList<String>,
    @StateNumberOne private val stateNumber: StateProgressBar.StateNumber,
) : EmailFragment<FragmentCalibrateRepairMessageBinding>(
    R.layout.fragment_calibrate_repair_message,
    progressBarDescription,
    stateNumber
) {
    // Overriding the values from EmailFragment
    override val next: Int by lazy { R.id.action_calibrateRepairMessageFragment_to_calibrateRepairUserDataFragment }
    override val bundleNext: Bundle by lazy { bundleOf("calibrate_repair_toolbar_text" to toolbarText) }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // ... some other stuff
    }
}
```

### Fragment 2

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class CalibrateRepairUserDataFragment(
    private val progressBarDescription: ArrayList<String>,
    @StateNumberTwo private val stateNumber: StateProgressBar.StateNumber,
) : EmailFragment<FragmentCalibrateRepairUserDataBinding>(
    R.layout.fragment_calibrate_repair_user_data,
    progressBarDescription,
    stateNumber
) {
    override val next: Int by lazy { R.id.action_calibrateRepairUserDataFragment_to_calibrateRepairDataOverviewFragment }
    override val bundleNext: Bundle by lazy { bundleOf("calibrate_repair_toolbar_text" to toolbarText) }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

I tried to delete everything that is not important for the question. You can ignore the constructor of `BaseFragment`, `EmailFragment`, `CalibrateRepairMessageFragment` and `CalibrateRepairUserDataFragment`. I am using navigation component and dagger-hilt.

I appreciate every help, thank you.

P.S: I've noticed that using `button:onClick` in the .xml file solves this problem but in this situation I can't use the xml version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with this should be your lazy initialization of `btnNext`.

The `Fragment1` state is saved when navigating to `Fragment2`. When navigating back the XML View will be reloaded but the lazy value of `btnNext` won't change as it is already initialized and is pointing to the old reference of the button view. Thus your `OnClickListener` will always be set to the old reference.

Instead of assigning your button lazily you should assign it in `EmailFragment`'s `onCreateView()`

PS: Also from `btn_next_calibrate` I suppose you are using kotlin synthetic view binding. If so you would not have to use a class variable.

Comment: It works, thank you very much (tried to fix it for hours)! But I've assigned my button in `onViewCreated()` instead of `onCreateView()`, does that make any difference?

Comment: `onViewCreated()` as mentioned in the Android docs is mostly used for subclasses to do their specific work. `onCreateView()` is usually the point where your base class does view logic that should be common for all subclasses.